# Stepping through a random string character by character?

Tags: bash, random

Working on this:
A simple game to echo a random keyboard character; then have the user match that character as fast as possible (this is not implemented yet (obviously) but that's the goal) and keep a running total of the "correct matches."

```
#!/bin/bash
score=0
while true; do
clear
echo "$score"
character=$(</dev/urandom tr -dc '1234567890{}[]`~\/><!@#$%^&*()_+=-abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' | head -c1)
echo "$character"
read -rsn1 input
if [ "$character" = "$input"]; then
  echo "[+]"
  score ++
  sleep 1
else
  echo "wrong!"
  score=0
  sleep 1
fi
done
```

Directly, my question is:
Why am I getting

```
[: missing `]'
```

error.
I have tried all variants of

```
if [ "$character" = "$input" ]; then
```

and second question:
How would I properly ask my next question which is: 
given a long random string, how would one "explode" that string such that it has a space in between every character? I do not have the experience/lexicon to describe this operation.

Much appreciated!

Comment: http://www.shellcheck.net/ is your friend :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be a space before the `]` like this:

```
if [ "$character" = "$input" ]; then
```

Also, to put bash in arithmetic mode, replace this line:

```
score ++
```

with:

```
((score ++))
```

Comment: If the OP had added that space, then that part of the code would have worked.  The other correction needed is `score ++` --> `((score++))`.

Comment: @john1024 you got me on the right track.. sadly still no go.

Comment: With those two corrections, your code works for me.  _"sadly still no go"_  When diagnosing computer problems, vagueness does not help: what didn't "go"?  Was there another error message?  If so, what was it _exactly_?  Or, did it run and not do what you expect?  If so, what did it do?  And, how did that differ from what you expected?

Comment: @john1024 Sorry for the vagueness. I know this... You're totally right. I had another syntax error. Thank you for your help! Now for the exploding with whitespace and underlining each character as you go... one thing at a time. =) cheers mate.